# Cant manually upload certificate in Node.js + express to heroku

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, heroku, https

Im trying to add my ssl certificate to my heroku app and im following the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl#manually-uploading-certificates-and-intermediaries).

so i configured my server accordingly and tried to run : heroku certs:add server.crt server.key 
buton then i get this error :  ENOENT: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\2\sportwiz\backend\server.crt'
my server is below :

```js
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const session = require('express-session')
var history=require('connect-history-api-fallback')
const addPredictRoutes = require('./routes/predictRoute')
const addUserRoutes = require('./routes/userRoute')
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express()
app.use(cors({
  origin: ['https://localhost:8080'],
  credentials: true // enable set cookie
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}))
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
  secret: 'lalala',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: false }
}))

app.use(history())

app.use(express.static('public'));
const port = process.env.PORT || 3003;

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./secrets/key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./secrets/cert.pem'),
};



var server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, function(){
console.log("Express server listening on port " + port);
});


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})


addPredictRoutes(app)
addUserRoutes(app)
```

What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: "then i get this error : ENOENT: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\2\sportwiz\backend\server.crt'"—let's start with the basics. Is there a file called `server.crt` in that location on your local machine?

Comment: thanks for the ccoment - no , i thought that this command refer to ther server object that contains the key and cert , but i also tried to run it with "key.pem" and "cert.pem" (the name of the files) but it didnt work too

Comment: Try renaming `key.pem` to `server.key` and `cert.pem` to `server.crt` and try again.

Comment: now i get the same error with the new name : ENOENT: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\2\sportwiz\backend\server.crt'

Comment: But you now have a file called `server.crt` in that location on your machine?

Comment: yes i changed the file name but it still doesnt help

Comment: Okay, there's likely something wrong with the files you have. Is there a specific reason you're jumping through all of these hoops instead of just using [ACM](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management)? It's much simpler and, in my opinion, a much better solution in most cases.